# What could cause a Zebra Printer to print "0/30" repeatedly instead of the image provided in a DG command?

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl, zpl-ii

I am sending images of the labels I want printed, one at a time, to a ZD421.
After around 100 were printed what was supposed to be a single label ended up being a stream of zeroes, with "30" under each, spread over several labels.

[Print result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MW1s2.jpg)

[Close up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5sZt.jpg)

The image sent was of a barcode with various related info in text around it.

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIWrM.png)

The ZPL sent for the labels looks like the following and the socket is closed after each is sent.

```
~DGR:label,40804,101,000...000(81608 characters of data)
^XA
^PON
^LH0,0
^LS0
^LL404
^PW808
^FO0,0
^XGR:label,1,1
^FS
^XZ
```

Restarting the printer fixed the problem and repeating the request printed the expected label.

My assumption was that reusing the name, "label", would overwrite previously sent graphics and there would be no memory management required. Is there something I should be sending to clean up after recalling the graphic?

Comment: Why are you sending all the information as image instead of plain text ZPL commands?

Comment: The information comes from PDFs generated by a separate system, where changes are easier to make and less disruptive to the business than the system that is communicating with the printer. This way the developers designing and making rare changes to the label were able to work with what they use on a daily basis, rather than learn and design in ZPL for this one process.

Comment: It would not be necessarily that hard to use ZPL right, there are a lot of libs available for different programming languages!

Comment: Is there something inherently wrong with using DG and XG with 40 kilobytes of data, like a pervasive and unavoidable memory leak in the printers?

Comment: Not that I know